# JdbcTemplate default date format

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I got method which takes random SQL statement and returns string representations of data.

```
String getDbValue(String sql, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, String.class);
}
```

Problems comes when I need to get date in specified format, because jdbc converts date to string itself.
Is there are any ways to set default formatting rules?
Something like:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.setDefaultDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I don't know type of column, thats why I can't read value into Date/Timestamp objects like:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, Timestamp.class);
```

! I understand that this is bad approach to get data from DB, but it's already part of project I'm working on and I can't change it

Comment: JDBC (which BTW is mostly an API/set of interfaces, not an implementation) doesn't convert dates to string, except maybe a driver specific formatting is applied when assigning a date or timestamp to a string field, maybe you should present your actual problem instead of your perceived solution for that problem. In that case: include the DDL of the table, and the database + driver you are using.

Comment: BTW: To your specific problem, if I'm guessing at the problem is, maybe you should use a row mapper or result set extractor instead.

Comment: I think that formatting depends on jdbc template because after changing ojdbc version from 6.11.2.0.3 to 7.12.1.0.1 date format changed from "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S" when reading from "DATE" columns.  I already know how to solve this problem in my case, I want to understand how jdbc formatting woks. Can I use it or it's undocumented functionality?

Comment: I'd assume that JDBC template is just using the `java.sql.Timestamp.toString()` or `java.sql.Date.toString`, which uses ISO-8601 format, but that doesn't depend on your driver version. So maybe it is using `getString(idx)` or `getObject(idx, String.class)`, which might lead to implementation specific behavior (although I would still expect it to use `Timestamp.toString()`). Maybe ojdbc version 11.2 was using its own `oracle.sql.DATE` instead, and 12.1 no longer does that or they extended it with subsecond information. In any case, relying on implementation details is not a good idea.